# Testing that express loads with mocha & chai

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

I'm having issues testing my express server where I'm expecting a 200 response back. When I run the test I get the error:

```
  Test server status
    1) server should return 200


  0 passing (260ms)
  1 failing

  1) Test server status
       server should return 200:
     TypeError: app.address is not a function
```

This is the spec file:

```
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiHttp from 'chai-http';
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

import server from '../server/server.js'


chai.use(chaiHttp);
let should = chai.should()


describe("Test server status", function () { 

  this.timeout(20000);

  it('server should return 200', async () => {
    const app = await server;

    return chai.request(app)
      .get('/helloworld')
      .then(res => {
        res.status.should.equal(200);
        res.body.message.should.equal('Hello World!');
      })
  })

})
```

I'm thinking the issue is that it's trying to test before the server is loaded. Any ideas? I'm using nextjs if that counts for something.

This is the server file:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';
import express from 'express'
import next from 'next'

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const app = next({ dev, dir: '.' })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()


mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://***********');
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  console.error(err);
  console.log('%s MongoDB connection error. Please make sure MongoDB is running.', chalk.red('✗'));
  process.exit(1);
});


app.prepare().then(() => {
  const server = express()

  server.get('/helloworld', (req, res) => {
    res.json({message:'Hello World!'})
  })

  server.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return handle(req, res)
  })

  server.listen(port, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`)
  })

})
```

I'm thinking maybe putting the server inside a class since I'm using ES6.

Answer (score 0):

Your server.js isn’t exporting a Promise, so await in your test does nothing.

Comment: When I try to export the server as a promise I get `'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level (37:2)`

Comment: Show your updated code please.  The issue is probably that you're trying to export it inside the `then` scoped function that you created it in.

Comment: That is correct. So how would I export the server if it's within the then function. Nextjs needs to run the prepare function first, before running the server.